# How to rewrite an abstract derivative of a sum as a sum of derivatives in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to convert (L + L')' into L' + L'' using sympy and some sort of expanding or simplifying function.

```py
import sympy
sympy.init_printing() # math as latex
z, L = sympy.symbols('z,L')
expr = sympy.Derivative(L + sympy.Derivative(L,z), z)
expr
```

[image]

I tried standard functions like `expand`, which rewrites the expression (even with a flag `force=True`), or `doit` which returns zero.

> **Question**. Is there a way to apply `sp.Derivative` to sum of two functions and expand it to sum of `sp.Derivative`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we work with derivatives, it is better to use `sympy.Function` instead of `sympy.Symbol`. In order to expand the derivative, one can use `.doit()` method.

> **Example.**

```py
import sympy
sympy.init_printing() # math as latex
z = sympy.Symbol('z')
f = sympy.Function("f")(z)
expr = sympy.Derivative(sympy.Derivative(f) + f)
expr
```

[image]

```py
expr.doit()
```

[image]